# Pagination Hibernate JPA: orderBy + setFirstResult + setMaxResult

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, limit

I have the following method which works:

```
public List<Course> filterOn(String course, String university, List<String> providers, String sortOn, int page) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
    Root r = criteriaQuery.from(Course.class);
    criteriaQuery.select(r);

    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(r.get("name"), "%" + course + "%"));
    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(r.get("university").get("name"), "%" + university + "%"));

    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.or(criteriaBuilder.like(r.get("type"), providers.get(0)),
                                      criteriaBuilder.like(r.get("type"), providers.get(1)),
                                      criteriaBuilder.like(r.get("type"), providers.get(2)),
                                      criteriaBuilder.like(r.get("type"), providers.get(3))));

    if (predicates != null && !predicates.isEmpty()) {
        criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
    }

    if (sortOn.equals("ranks")) {
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(r.get("averageScoreLastSemester")));
    } else if (sortOn.equals("name")) {
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(r.get("name")));
    }

    final TypedQuery query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

    query.setFirstResult(page * COURSES_PER_PAGE);
    query.setMaxResults(COURSES_PER_PAGE);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

The problem is that it only orders the current page. I want it ordered in relation to all matched records in the database and then just return current page. How can I do this?

From the logs:

```
select
        course0_.id as id1_14_,
        course0_.created as created2_14_,
        course0_.updated as updated3_14_,
        course0_.averageScoreLastSemester as averageS4_14_,
        course0_.avgAverageArray as avgAvera5_14_,
        course0_.avgStructureArray as avgStruc6_14_,
        course0_.avgTeachersArray as avgTeach7_14_,
        course0_.avgWorkloadArray as avgWorkl8_14_,
        course0_.code as code9_14_,
        course0_.courseLink as courseL10_14_,
        course0_.credits as credits11_14_,
        course0_.level as level12_14_,
        course0_.name as name13_14_,
        course0_.numberOfAssignments as numberO14_14_,
        course0_.numberOfExams as numberO15_14_,
        course0_.numberOfProjects as numberO16_14_,
        course0_.pace as pace17_14_,
        course0_.rankCountArray as rankCou18_14_,
        course0_.requirementsLink as require19_14_,
        course0_.semester as semeste20_14_,
        course0_.teacherName as teacher21_14_,
        course0_.type as type22_14_,
        course0_.university_id as univers23_14_ 
    from
        courses course0_ cross 
    join
        universities university1_ 
    where
        course0_.university_id=university1_.id 
        and (
            course0_.name like ?
        ) 
        and (
            university1_.name like ?
        ) 
        and (
            course0_.type like ? 
            or course0_.type like ? 
            or course0_.type like ? 
            or course0_.type like ?
        ) 
    order by
        course0_.name desc limit ?
Hibernate: 
    select
        course0_.id as id1_14_,
        course0_.created as created2_14_,
        course0_.updated as updated3_14_,
        course0_.averageScoreLastSemester as averageS4_14_,
        course0_.avgAverageArray as avgAvera5_14_,
        course0_.avgStructureArray as avgStruc6_14_,
        course0_.avgTeachersArray as avgTeach7_14_,
        course0_.avgWorkloadArray as avgWorkl8_14_,
        course0_.code as code9_14_,
        course0_.courseLink as courseL10_14_,
        course0_.credits as credits11_14_,
        course0_.level as level12_14_,
        course0_.name as name13_14_,
        course0_.numberOfAssignments as numberO14_14_,
        course0_.numberOfExams as numberO15_14_,
        course0_.numberOfProjects as numberO16_14_,
        course0_.pace as pace17_14_,
        course0_.rankCountArray as rankCou18_14_,
        course0_.requirementsLink as require19_14_,
        course0_.semester as semeste20_14_,
        course0_.teacherName as teacher21_14_,
        course0_.type as type22_14_,
        course0_.university_id as univers23_14_ 
    from
        courses course0_ cross 
    join
        universities university1_ 
    where
        course0_.university_id=university1_.id 
        and (
            course0_.name like ?
        ) 
        and (
            university1_.name like ?
        ) 
        and (
            course0_.type like ? 
            or course0_.type like ? 
            or course0_.type like ? 
            or course0_.type like ?
        ) 
    order by
        course0_.name desc limit ?
```

I guess the last line is important, I read somewhere that it should first sort all records and then limit them. So it seems correct?

Im using the hibernate dialect `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` and the datasource using `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

Thank you.

Comment: all records in the database? but you are using restrictions (with like). I'm not seen any error.

Comment: But the query is strange (like constructions), is not common search by diferrents entities (course *and* university).

Comment: I mean I want to get all courses that match some attributes like name, university, provider and so on. This works. But from that subset I want to order by either course score or name. And then return one page at the time. This is not working. It returns one page but it is only sorted within that page and not compared to all matches like I want.

Comment: Each course has an university connected to it. Thats why I'm filtering on each courses university as well before sorting.

Comment: Maybe a problem with the view technology? Did you run Sysout resultList to confirm that sort order problem is from JPA? When you change to second page, the filters still there?

Comment: Yes you are right @Reinaldo Gil. Something happened on the view side of the application. The code above actually worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a problem with the view technology? Did you run Sysout resultList to confirm that sort order problem is from JPA? When you change to second page, the filters still there?